# How to ensure all files share the same structure in Python?

Tags: python, file, structure

I have a file where the first line is the sport category and the following lines are semicolon separated values where each of them follow the same structure: str-str-int-int.

How would you go about reading and processing these files and in case of a different structure, raise an error? I'd like to check length of the string list and also the type

Sample input:

```
BASKETBALL
player 1; Peter; 23; 15;
player 2; Steve; 14; 10;
```

Sample error:

```
FOOTBALL
player 4; Carl; ten; 22; 15;
```

Thanks

Comment: player 4; Carl; ten; 22; 15; How you want to do with this line, by pass or just select the desired result? player 4;Carl;22;15?

Comment: What did you try and why are you unhappy with it? Please post your code.

Comment: I used split(";") with strip() and checked the length of the result, if it was not the same, I raised an error. I was stucked with the numbers in words without using regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific data pattern, you can use [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to check the structure of your data:

```
import re

# Here is the specific pattern you want to match
regex = re.compile(r'^player \d+; [A-Z][a-z]+; \d+; \d+;$')
filename = 'sport.txt'
# Test for each file
with open(filename) as f:
    header = f.readline().strip()
    for line in f:
        if not regex.match(line):
            # You can also catch this Error and do some other things
            raise ValueError('Line Not Match: ' + line)

print('Sports {} in {} is GOOD!'.format(header, filename))
```